# Fixing/ignoring unclosed tags in xml with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xls

I'm getting an xml file back from a client and there is data in there that looks like unclosed tags, but is intended to represent data. For instance, NULL values are passed back as `<null>`.

Is there a way to clean this up with an xsl (1.0) without third party libraries? I'm already trying to parse this with xsl, but when it encounters one of these values, the transformation fails and I just get unformatted text (when viewed in a browser.)

Sample xml:

```
<Execution>...</Execution>
<Error>
    <Message>
        Failed to execute [elementType=<null>, 
            name=<null>,
                id=<null>
    </Message>
</Error>
```

Ideally, I'd like to convert the `<null>` values to `NULL`.

I'm new to xslt and my searches haven't turned up anything helpful for my specific issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As it is invalid XML I don't think XSLT is going to be able to cope with it.  You will need to do a search and replace before the XSLT executes

Comment: If the client would be required to deliver valid XML, then he is obviously failing, you might get him to use `&lt;null&gt;` which "looks similar"

Comment: XSLT is for processing XML. It's not the right tool for processing non-XML.